# Single statement conditionals - why is the pattern not used for other code blocks?

Tags: c#

Just thought I'd see if somebody could explain why Anders decided that this is valid...

```
if(...)
   //single statement
else
   ///single statement
```

but this is not...

```
try
   //single statement
catch
   //single statement
```

Comment: pedant: it isn't "one line" - it is "one statement"

Comment: @Marc: I hardly think that's a pedantic distinction. I fact, I suspect it's the actual answer to the question.

Comment: @Cody - well, you could arguably have one statement in the try, and one statement in the catch... don't get me wrong though; I **want** braces there ;p

Comment: I've checked the spec "Special Annotated Edition for C# 3.0", but it doesn't say anything on this

Comment: Anders was kind enough not to declare millions of lines of codes written by many coders before he was born. So, he had both options for `if` open :D

Comment: Wouldn't it be lovely if we could just do away with the single statement / compound statement mess!

Comment: @DavidH. For me, no. I find that single statement code blocks such as this are equally readable - in fact I find them more readable as it reduces the number of unnecessary lines in code. When I want to separate code then **I** will create some whitespace.

Comment: @David Neale Modula-2 got it right. Python gets it right. C/C++/Java/C#/Perl/Pascal all get it wrong. Entering holy war territory here!!  ;-)

Comment: @David Neale: Sure, it's just as readable when there's a single statement. The problem comes *later*, when you or some other unsuspecting developer adds a second (or a third) statement, without noticing the lack of curly braces. And problems that only crop up later are *far* worse. Anything that makes debugging and future maintainability easier is something I'm on board with. For the record, VB/VB.NET gets this right, too. Curly braces have a lot to answer for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To quote from [Framework Design Guidelines](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321246756) in the section about "General Style Conventions" this is said about braces:

> **AVOID** omitting braces, even if the language allows it. Braces should not
>   be considered optional. Even for
>   single statement blocks, you should
>   use braces. This increase code
>   readability and maintainability.
>
> There are very limited cases when
>   omitting braces might be acceptable,
>   such as when adding a new statement
>   after an existing singöe-line
>   statement is either impossible or
>   extremely rare. For example, it is
>   meaningless to add a statement after a
>   `throw` statement:
>
> `if(someExpression) throw new
>   ArgumentOutOfRangeExcetion(...);`
>
> Another exception to the rule is
>   braces in case statements. These
>   braces can be omitted as the `case`and
>   `break`statements indicate the
>   begining and the start of the block.

What Anders thinks is subjective and argumentative, this is the recommendation.

You might also want to look at the section about bracing in the [coding convention over at msdn.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2005/01/26/361363.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Probably because single statement conditionals are historically valid in curly brace languages,  but the other patterns are not.

Since either example makes code less readable in general there is no good reason to introduce single statement support further than historically necessary.

If you image you extended single statement support to lots of code blocks you can quite easily see someone writing totally unreadable code.  Personally I would avoid the first case too.