# Why try-catch statements must have { } in C#?

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, syntax, grammar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Single statement conditionals - why is the pattern not used for other code blocks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943408/single-statement-conditionals-why-is-the-pattern-not-used-for-other-code-blocks)
>   [C#: Why does Try-Catch require curly braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3999422/c-why-does-try-catch-require-curly-braces)

This is kind of a C# compiler/syntax question:

Why can't we have the following in C#:

```
try
  MethodCall() //Only one line here, of course
catch (Exception ex)
  //Do a one-line action here
```

instead of

```
try {
  MethodCall() //Only one line here, of course
}     
catch (Exception ex) {
  //Do a one-line action here
}
```

Is it because that would make C# grammar ambiguous or something like that?

I'm just curious, because we can perfectly do:

```
if (something)
  Action1();
else
  Action2();
```

Comment: I second this.  Exactly the same ground.

Comment: Not entirely sure, but i suppose it's mostly for clarity's sake.
I can imagine you want to be very specific, and clear about what is 'tried' and 'caught'.
if `try` would be noted as `try MethodCall() catch CatchCall();`, it would not be so obvious to who reads the code as it is now.

Comment: I think you shuold change the duplicate to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3999422/c-why-does-try-catch-require-curly-braces. What I asked is not an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943408/single-statement-conditionals-why-is-the-pattern-not-used-for-other-code-blocks !

Comment: Enclosing even single-line blocks in braces makes the code *much* easier to maintain long-term. It prevents the possibility of someone coming along and adding a line of code, not realizing that it won't ever get called. There seems little point in *not* using braces; most coding standards recommend it as a matter of course, including Microsoft's.

Comment: @Cody Gray that depends on the programming language. Some languages (Python, Haskell,..) are more into indentation, but I agree with you. I was just curious about why they did this, but I'm seeing a good example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3999422/c-why-does-try-catch-require-curly-braces

Comment: @Oscar: Yup, the insight that Eric provides there is very interesting, and I very much agree with kidjan's answer. My last comment was assuming a C-style syntax. I have my own opinions about curly braces, but they're not terribly popular I've noticed.